# Integrate Smarty Site with Drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, smarty

I am currently working on a site which is on smarty based.The name of the site is `http://example.com`

I built a new folder in the root path and installed droupon (which is a component of drupal for buying or creating any deal) on the folder.The site url is `http://example.com/coupon`

Now I want to integrate or merge this two sites.So that when a registered user access `example.com` then he can access the `example.com/coupon` with his session user id.

But this is the problem.

**Is this really possible to pass data from smarty based site (`example.com`) to drupal site `example.com/coupon` ?**

Please help me.

Comment: It's not Smarty related. It's just pure PHP. Just use sessions and it will work

Comment: You need to read about session and look at Drupal documentation

Comment: I know PHP SESSION and worked with it in normal php site.But I dont know how to pass the session from normal php to drupal. @Marcin .

Answer (score 0):

I would write at module in Drupal that looks at $_SESSION and creates and/or login the user at the Drupal-site. Perhaps the rules module can do that work, but you will probably need to implement a rules-hook to grab the relevant session data as input to the rules component.

Here are a few lines of code that do some of the work but you need to implement hook_menu aswell to register an entrypoint for the integration.

```
 //register user
 $passwd = user_password();
 $edit = array(
    'name' => $_SESSION['username'],
    'pass' => $passwd,
    'mail' => $_SESSION['email'],
    'init' => $_SESSION['email'],
    'status' => 1,
    'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
 );
 $uu = drupal_anonymous_user();
 $u = user_save($uu, $edit);

 //Login
 global $user;
 $user = user_load($u->uid);
 $login_array = array ('name' => $username);
 user_login_finalize($login_array);
```

However, Im not sure this is the best way to go about it. Sharing data in the same session-namespace between 2 different applications will probably lead to errors on both sides. Is it not better to implement the whole site in Drupal from the beginning?